# EF Code First: Object with One-to-Many and M-T-M of same classes fails to generate M-T-M in db

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following classes (shortened)

```
Game

{
public int id {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Player> Players {get;set;}
public virtual Player Owner {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters {get;set;}
}

Players
{
public int id {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Game> Games {get;set;}
}

Characters
{
public virtual ICollection<Game> Games {get;set;}
}
```

For whatever reason, my database generates a one-to-many link for Game-Players.
It does, however, create one for games-characters.

I have no idea why this would be, other than perhaps the one-to-many is screwing with it in some way!

Comment: I manually added it into my dbcontext intializer and it worked... Very weird though!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Game` class has *two* navigation properties to the `Player` class. EF doesn't know which one to map to the target `Player.Games`. Because of that it decides that there are actually three relationships:

- `Game.Players <-> not exposed`
- `Game.Owner <-> not exposed`
- `Player.Games <-> not exposed`

And the fourth relationship is

- `Game.Characters <-> Character.Games`

For the last one EF detects the right ends of the relationship because they are not ambiguous.

The easiest way to fix that is to give EF a hint which of the two navigation properties on `Game` refering to `Player` actually belongs to `Player.Games`:

```
public class Game
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    [InverseProperty("Games")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players {get;set;}
    public virtual Player Owner {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters {get;set;}
}
```

Now the result are the expected three relationships:

- `Game.Players <-> Player.Games`
- `Game.Owner <-> not exposed`
- `Game.Characters <-> Character.Games`

Instead of using the `[InverseProperty]` attribute you can also specify this in Fluent API by explicitely mapping a many-to-many relationship between `Game.Players` and `Player.Games`.

Answer (score 0):

The `public int id` is the default variable name for EF Code first **key** values. It does recognize this **implicitly**.

This key value is omitted in Characters, and therefore handled differently.